# How do I install pandas_datareader?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I want to learn about pandas_datareader with jupyter notebooks. When I tried installing it through anaconda prompt, I got the error message:

```
EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: C:\...
```

what does it mean? How can i use pandas_datareader with jupyter notebooks?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pandas library in to your machine using `pip install pandas` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your jupyter notebook

```
!pip install pandas-datareader
```